# How to locate GUID in hex of compiled Windows executable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hex, guid

I have a Windows bootstrapper application that I compile myself (deep down it uses C# and WPF), but the framework I must use to program it doesn't let me change a particular GUID that it stores in the Windows registry when it installs MSI packages (it forces me to program the bootstrapper in XML and does not expose this GUID as an XML-modifiable property), and I know that this GUID takes on a specific, hard-coded value. This value changes whenever I recompile the bootstrapper executable. I want to be able to modify this GUID on a post-build script in order to keep it the same.

My question is this, is it possible to find the location of that GUID from a hex dump? I have searched my hex dump of the executable, trying to convert from GUID to hex, or from GUID string to ASCII or hex, etc, and I have tried getting a better grasp of things using `ILDASM` but that did not help. I am not sure how a GUID is stored in a compiled executable...has anyone had success with this? If so, how is the GUID stored and what did you have to do to access it?

The GUID it installs in the registry at the moment is `{E66D1133-9A23-4E07-8DB1-0A3A4A7F7B35}`.

Comment: @AJHenderson **You are confusing MSI GUIDs with my bootstrapper registration GUID.** A change to the GUID I am talking about will **NOT** break anything. Trust me, I've been doing installers for a long time now.

Comment: Fair enough, still not seeing anything about this security related though.  Even if you need it to be the same for some security purpose, this falls under technical implementation methods which aren't generally on topic here, but rather on the site most related to implementing it (ie, StackOverflow in this case)

Comment: @AJHenderson Well, my thought is that its not a programming question either. I'm not looking for code, but an explanation. The best place for it in my mind is `security.stackexchange.com`...where I'd expect people to understand the low-level workings of compilers in Windows and how they store data. This could easily become a security question, such as, "How to mask GUIDs in an application so that someone can't find them from a hex dump?" for which you'd need to know how to find them first. Like anything in life, you can't perform something better without knowing how to first measure it.

Comment: If Stack Exchange or Security Exchange aren't the place to go, what would you have me do? Can we just please focus on the problem at hand here? It has many security principles and aspects that would be beneficial to any developer or just someone focused on security penetration testing. This should be something fundamental to security, at least it is in my mind. You need to know how data is stored in a program, application, or file in order to know how to manipulate it.

Comment: @Alexandru AJ is correct, this is not a security question, and is not particularly beneficial.  I'd suggest that your real question is not the one you've posed, but this:  You want the application GUID to remain constant across multiple compilations.  This is a straight up development question that would fit perfectly on StackOverflow.  I wouldn't leap to the conclusion is that the only option is to modify the resulting binary, and even if it is, it still isn't a security question.

Comment: @Xander I don't want a programming question, because I have tried; that did not have a definitive solution for this case; I've said above that the framework I use does not let me change this GUID (I cannot change it in the application's code, I really can't, its coded through XML and it does not expose this GUID as a parameter). The only way to change it would be by modifying a hex dump. No matter how you cut it, the end result is you will need to figure out how to get the location of that GUID from a dump of the executable. Trust me on this.

Comment: @Alexandru Regardless this is not the venue for searching a binary for a specific value.  You might have better luck in the [Reverse Engineering SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @raz Thanks Raz, that is a good idea. I will do that if SE does not turn up anything (question got migrated).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a WiX bootstrapper. If so, let's assume it's named Wix39.exe and is in the current directory.

```
"%WIX%\bin\dark" Wix39.exe -x "%TEMP%\dark.tmp" && ^
find "WixBundleProperties" "%TEMP%\dark.tmp\UX\BootstrapperApplicationData.xml" & ^
rmdir /s/q "%TEMP%\dark.tmp"
```

You are looking for WixBundleProperties/@Id.

Comment: Tom, after making a change to BootstrapperApplicationData.xml, how would I recompile with the new settings, or append the changes to my existing executable?

Comment: I don't think the current tools support that. You should probably look at creating a custom version of burn; maybe defeat [RegistrationDetectInstalled](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/burn/engine/registration.cpp).

Comment: I was trying to steer away from customizing the burn tool, since then I'd have to compile the same customization on every update. :( Plus, it would be cool to figure out how to modify a GUID from an executable's dump.